# How can I use Blackberry emojis on my non-jailbroken iOS device?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, emoji

Ever since moving from my Blackberry to an iPhone a few years ago, I've been sorely missing the Blackberry emoji set. It was pretty brilliant, and contained some KEY emoji which Apple seems to deem unimportant, including the much sought-after face palm (why leave this out Apple, WHY??).

Anyone have any idea on how I can get these prized Blackberry emojis onto a non-jailbroken iPhone for use in Messages? I've been trying to save them as images and paste them into IM, but this method makes the emoji look too large, and it ends up looking pixelated.

Would it possible to create and install my own custom keyboard? Any other methods or idea would be welcome.

Thanks!

Additional note: I can re-create/convert the Blackberry emoji in vector form, all I really need to know is how to install it as a keyboard. Is this possible on non-jailbroken devices? Alternately, is there a way to send a vector image through IM?

Comment: emoji have been standardized internationally via Uncode.org since 2011, and that is what all modern devices should normally display.   Something old from Blackberry that was not included in this would not likely be supported these days.    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji

Comment: *unicode (not uncode)

Answer (score 1):

iOS 8 supports 3rd party keyboards. There are several that speak in icons and gifs and whatnot. Check the AppStore for something you like or even develop your own.

Comment: Thanks. So if I wanted to develop my own keyboard, how would I go about doing that, and more importantly, how do I load it onto my iOS device?

Comment: @OohMamma See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html